# Resample pandas DataFrame of OHLC data into three-day bars ignoring weekends

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have daily price data with Open, High, Low, Close and the date as the index.  I want to create three-day bars, but I want the bars to "wrap around the weekend," so that I end up with MTuW, TuWTh, WThF, ThFM, and FMTu bars.

(MTuW = Monday Tuesday Wednesday)

(FMTu = Friday Monday Tuesday)

(FSaSu = Friday Saturday Sunday)

I tried

```
df = df.asfreq('B')
df = df.resample('3D').mean()
```

But that seems to work properly only for MTuW, TuWTh, and WThF bars.  The other bars don't seem to skip the weekend days, meaning that what is intended to be a FMTu bar is actually a FSaSu bar, or more accurately simply a Friday bar.

I believe there is a way to make this work perhaps with

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
```

But it's not clear to me exactly how to make it work.

Comment: Care to share some sample data? Your code looks sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test this but I think you just need to use:

`df = df.resample('3B').mean()`

### Update

To also accommodate for holidays, use a custom rule to resample:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

bday_us = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

df = df.resample(bday_us).mean()
```

I used `USFederalHolidayCalendar` here. To get an overview of the holidays in such a holiday class:

```
>>> pprint(USFederalHolidayCalendar().rules)
[Holiday: New Years Day (month=1, day=1, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10db3ce18>),
 Holiday: Dr. Martin Luther King Jr. (month=1, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+3)>),
 Holiday: Presidents Day (month=2, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+3)>),
 Holiday: MemorialDay (month=5, day=31, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(-1)>),
 Holiday: July 4th (month=7, day=4, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10db3ce18>),
 Holiday: Labor Day (month=9, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+1)>),
 Holiday: Columbus Day (month=10, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+2)>),
 Holiday: Veterans Day (month=11, day=11, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10db3ce18>),
 Holiday: Thanksgiving (month=11, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=TH(+4)>),
 Holiday: Christmas (month=12, day=25, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10db3ce18>)]
```

Obviously such a holiday object can be customised and built from scratch too. More info on holiday classes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#holidays-holiday-calendars

Comment: This is simple and elegant, thanks very much!  One problem, though, is that it skips weekends, but it does not skip trading holidays.  So, for example, there is no data for Monday, Jan 15, 2018 (Martin Luther King Jr Day), but my three-day bars that include that day are made up of only two trading days and that empty day.  I believe this realization changes my question.  I need to resample by grouping every three data bars, ignoring day of week.  Is that easy to answer in a comment, or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Updated my answer. Looks like for your specific case you could use `df = df.resample(3 * bday_us).mean()`. Can you confirm this?